# Como setear una propiedad de la propiedad de un modelo en angular 4

Tags: angular4

Me parece que la propiedad está indefinida cuando intentó inicializar la propiedad de un objeto al inicio en el constructor. Eso ocurre en el template por ejemplo si no hago esto

Objeto?.firstname = 'a';

Me dice que firstname es indefinida. Como hago esto en el typescript  din que me diga esto

Answer (score 0):

Para iniciar la propiedad de un objeto desde el constructor debes acceder a esta con this.

```
this.tuObjeto.tuPropiedad = 'tuValor';
```